# IntelliJ Community Edition Hanging on Plugin Cloud Code

Tags: intellij-idea, google-cloud-code

I installed Cloud Code for IntelliJ Community Edition 2022.2.1 and IntelliJ hung. I have let it run for over 20 minutes but there is no change. This is the second time this has happened (I reinstalled IntelliJ the first time). Could this have anything to do with having many complicated Maven pom.xml files in multiple projects?

The screen is stuck on the Popup text and showing that there is an upgrade pending.

The issue arises after I install the Cloud Code plug-in. The version of Cloud Code that I installed is: Cloud Code - 22.9.2-221.

Comment: Do you face the issue with plugin installed only?

Comment: What is your Cloud Code plugin version and your operating system? Thanks!

Comment: Oh I see you have the latest version of Cloud Code. Did you make any actions or run any applications using Cloud Code, or it hangs immediately after you install the plugin? What operating system are you running on? Thanks!

Comment: It hangs almost immediately. It started doing a dump after I click on the do not auto-update Cloud SDK. I am running Windows 10 with the latest patches.

Comment: Thanks @DavidGordon, could you give us a bit of history please - since you see a dialog about updating Cloud SDK, this means Cloud Code was previously installed Cloud SDK of older version, and the new version is available. Is this correct assumption? To confirm, IDE started fine, you *just installed* Cloud Code (and previously installed it before since Cloud SDK was outdated), and clicked "Disable automatic updates" on update notification, and at this point, it froze?

Comment: It wasn't just Cloud SDK. To confirm I had the latest version of the SDK downloaded I went into Powershell and confirmed that I had the latest version of the SDK. The problem occurred both when I did and did not click on the update the Cloud SDK i.e. the screen freezing. I am beginning to think that it is something wrong with my proxy since I am sitting behind the proxy of my company.

Comment: I see. How do you configure your proxies - do you use IntelliJ proxy configuration settings (it does have a separate proxy configuration settings), or it's on the OS level only? Do you see anything (like unusual exceptions or something related to UI freeze) in your IDE log - to get one, go to Help -> Show Log in Files?

Comment: As you suggested I put in my proxy settings and it didn't hang. Unfortunately, I know get the error (See below). Any thoughts on this?

Plugin "Cloud Code" was not installed: Cannot download 'https://plugins.jetbrains.com/pluginManager/?id=com.google.gct.core&build=IC-222.3739.54&uuid=1508221cb1592ba-e5aa-490b-8c4d-cf68ec8f60c2': Connection closed at byte

Comment: It seems like IDE cannot access its own repository with plugins - sounds like another network issue. You can also downloads the plugin directly (it's a zip file), then go Settings -> Plugins -> Plugin Settngs (little gear icon) -> Install from disk -> Select downloaded ZIP file and that should install Cloud Code.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it installed the plug-in. Unfortunately, after that the system locked up on “Initializing managed Kubernetes dependencies”. Another person in my team has the same issue, so I don't think it is just my machine.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks, we are looking into it. I assume all team members use proxies? Is it possible for you to get us idea.log file to see what's happening in more detail (see instructions above)

Comment: Everybody in the team uses proxies (same one). Is there a place I can "securely" send the idea.log? I don't want to "upset" our security group.

Comment: Please file an issue here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij/issues. As for sensitive information in your idea.log, only you know which one is sensitive - as an option, you can only paste exceptions or logging snippets related to Cloud Code - those doesn't contain much of user information except for local file system paths - please remove them too. Sorry for inconvenience. Thank you again, we are still looking into this.

Comment: The fix for Cloud Code plugin has been identified and in progress. While we are preparing a release with this fix, a possible workaround:

Kill hanging skaffold.exe process (child process of IntelliJ IDEA in the Windows task manager) and this immediately unblocks the IDE process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for Cloud Code plugin has been released - please update to the latest plugin version (`22.10.1-222/221`).

This should fix the hanging when opening new projects (especially large one on slower Windows machines) with Cloud Code installed.

If you get your IDE hanging when opening a project in Windows and need to unblock to install a fixed version of Cloud Code, go to Windows Task Manager, find IntelliJ IDEA, expand list of child processes, and kill `skaffold.exe` process - this should unblock IDE immediately. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: The plugin is working fine; however, every time I open IntelliJ it creates a new "dmp" file. Is this related to the plugin or is this an IntelliJ error.

Comment: @DavidGordon could you please share dmp file via drop box or google drive to take a look - it should not have any sensitive information except for code stacktraces. Thanks!

Comment: the files are empty but one that got created today was called:

core.20221029.173046.3220.0001.dmp